# Disqus Commenting without notification on top

Tags: wordpress, comments, disqus

[image]

I want to remove the Your site is using the new Disqus. Check the Disqus 2012 F.A.Q. or visit...  Is there a place to turn off this notification??

Answer (score 0):

Someone responded to this request on another thread: [How to remove Disqus reaction from the counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137162/how-to-remove-disqus-reaction-from-the-counter) But to me its not clear where this CSS is to be placed, so it would be great if someone could help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom CSS code on disqus, just add it on the appearance section http://disqus.com/admin/settings/appearance/

```
#disqus_thread #help-notice{
     display:none;
}
```