# How to remove Disqus reaction from the counter?

Tags: comments, wordpress, disqus

**Two questions for Stackoverflow ninjas:**

1. I have a blog using Disqus. However, the theme I'm using do not have space to have the 'Reactions' (# of Twitters), just have the space for the numbers of the Comments.
   OK, Basically I do not have space enough to stay with this 'Reactions' provided for Disqus. Does anyone knows how could I remove just the 'Reactions" counts from Disqus?
2. The new Disqus put a box with "Your site is using the new Disqus. Check the Disqus 2012 F.A.Q. or visit our support page for help." message and I would love to remove it. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

**Edit 2: We've made this easier by including the comment count/reaction count text options back in the Disqus settings. This is now possible by simply going to your Disqus admin and adding the HTML tags mentioned in the original answer below.**

**Edit 1: As of a couple of weeks ago the below solution is no longer valid due to the deprecation of the Disqus Classic settings. For now the only way to remove the reaction counter would be to disable reactions entirely, or use the [Disqus API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/set/) to get raw thread data.**

In Disqus Classic we had a way to change the comment count link text in the appearance settings. We're working on adding it back to Disqus 2012, but for now you can get around it by following these steps:

1. Go to your Disqus admin's general settings and uncheck "Enable Disqus 2012" at the very top
2. After you click Save Changes, you'll see a new tab along the top called "Appearance" - click that
3. In your Appearance settings, scroll down to "Comment count link"
4. Remove the word "Comment(s)" from each entry. Then you'll want to insert some HTML with an inline style of "display:none;" to remove the reaction text.

Here's what all of the fields should look like to just get a number:

```
Zero Comments      | 0<span style="display:none;">
One Comment        | 1<span style="display:none;">
Multiple Comments  | {num}<span style="display:none;">

Zero Reactions     | 0 Reactions</span>
One Reaction       | 1 Reaction</span>
Multiple Reactions | {num} Reactions</span>
```

Now you can go ahead an re-enable Disqus 2012 again and the comment count link preferences will carry over.

We've also turned off the "New Disqus" header.

Comment: I'm using Disqus 2012 features and I wanted to disable only the reactions count, but leave comments count on. I went to "Manage / General" and unchecked "Enable Reactions". However, the reaction count was still there.

I then disabled Disqus 2012 and re-enabled it and the reaction was gone. It seems that this refreshed something that was still holding the reactions enabled.

Comment: It should be noted that turning off "Enable Disqus 2012" is no longer an option. An alternate solution is required to handle this problem.

Comment: Thanks, answer has been updated. A better alternative is being worked on as well.

Comment: @RyanV about edit 3 : can save `<span>` but not `<span style="display:none;">` maybe because of the quotes ... so I used css : `.dsq-comment-count span{display:none;}`

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck "Enable Disqus 2012 features for your site", then go to the appearance tab and there you'll find the comment count and reaction settings which you can customize the words as you want.

Comment: Disabling Disqus 2012 is no longer an available option.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment on the top answer, but I don't have 50 reputation points, so I can't comment. Instead, please consider this answer an add-on to the suggestion to turn off Disqus 2012 and turn it back on again if your changes don't take effect.

I had this problem using the Disqus Wordpress plugin. Now that turning off Disqus 2012 features is no longer an option, deactivating and then reactivating the plugin seems to have the same effect of refreshing whatever it is that is holding reactions enabled.

Answer (score -1):

2) You can do it with CSS.

```css
#help-notice {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use custom CSS code on disqus, just add it on the appearance section
http://disqus.com/admin/settings/appearance/

```css
#disqus_thread #help-notice {
    display: none;
}
```