# Remove Disqus Reactions from Widget?

Tags: comments, wordpress, disqus

I found this question about removing "Reactions" from Disqus: [How to remove Disqus reaction from the counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137162/how-to-remove-disqus-reaction-from-the-counter), but it appears to be outdated, because I can't find those options on the current version of Disqus.

On my blog, http://ilovetheupperwestside.com, when you view a post, the Disqus text "X Comments and Y Reactions" conflicts with the design of the "Recent Posts" sidebar widget.

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the reactions part. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check disqus plugin source. There was a hook that trigger to loop. After commetimg it - everything will become good.